# $x_1 \leq 4, x_1+x_2 \leq 13, x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 29, x_1+...+x_4 \leq 54, x_1+...+x_5 \leq 90$. Find the maximum of ...

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

> $x_1 \leq 4, x_1+x_2 \leq 13, x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 29, x_1+...+x_4 \leq 54, x_1+...+x_5 \leq 90 \text{ for } x_1, ..., x_5 \in R_0^+. \\ \ \\ \text{Find the maximum of } \sqrt{x_1}+\sqrt{x_2}+\sqrt{x_3}+\sqrt{x_4}+\sqrt{x_5}.$

Of course, the answer will be $20(x_1=4, x_2=9, x_3=16, x_4=25, x_5=36.)$

My attempt:
\begin{align}
&\text{let } \sum_k \ x_l = x_l+x_{l+1}+x_{l+2}+...+x_{k+l-1}. \ (x_{5n+m}=x_m) \\
&\bigg(\sum_5 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg)^2 \leq 5\bigg(\sum_5 x_1\bigg) \leq 450. \\
&\therefore \bigg( \sum_5 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg) \leq 15\sqrt{2}. \\
\ \\
&\bigg(\sum_4 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg)^2 \leq 4\bigg(\sum_4 x_1 \bigg) \leq 216. \\
&\therefore \bigg( \sum_4 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg) \leq 6\sqrt{6}. \\
\ \\
&\bigg(\sum_3 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg)^2 \leq 3\bigg(\sum_3 x_1 \bigg) \leq 87. \\
&\therefore \bigg(\sum_3 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg) \leq \sqrt{87}. \\
\ \\
&\bigg(\sum_2 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg)^2 \leq 2\bigg(\sum_2 x_1 \bigg) \leq 26. \\
&\therefore \bigg(\sum_2 \sqrt{x_1} \bigg) \leq \sqrt{26}. \\
\ \\
&\bigg(\sqrt{x_1} \bigg)^2 \leq 4. \\
&\therefore  \sqrt{x_1} \leq 2. \\
\end{align}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$x_1 \leq 4 \tag {1}$$ $$x_1+x_2 \leq 13\tag{2}$$ $$x_1+x_2+x_3 \leq 29\tag{3}$$ $$x_1+...+x_4 \leq 54\tag {4}$$ $$x_1+...+x_5 \leq 90\tag 5$$

now $$(5)\times 10+(4)\times 2+(3)\times 3+(2)\times 5+(1)\times 10 \implies$$  $$10x_5+12x_4+15x_3+20x_2+30x_1\le 1200$$ also by C-S $${\left(10x_5+12x_4+15x_3+20x_2+30x_1 \right)}{\left(\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{15}+\frac{1}{20}+\frac{1}{30}\right)}\ge {\left(\sum \sqrt{x_i}\right)}^2$$ can you end it now?

Comment: Alright, Thanks! I think I can end this one.

Comment: @Math great! I hope you understand why i multiplied the equations by specific numbers ... it was to preserve the equality case

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore How did you preserved equality case by multiplying with specific numbers

Comment: @LalitTolani I expected $\sum x \leq 20$. Therefore $ETS) \Big( \sum x \Big)^2 \leq 400$. So, Albus just made $\frac 1 {a_5}, \frac 1 {a_4}, \frac 1 {a_3}, \frac 1 {a_2}, \frac 1 {a_1}$ which satisfies $(90a_5+54(a_4-a_5)+29(a_3-a_4)+13(a_2-a_3)+4(a_1-a_2))\Big(\frac 1 {a_5}+\frac 1 {a_4}+\frac 1 {a_3}+\frac 1 {a_2}+\frac 1 {a_1}\Big) = 400, \text{ And the value of those are } \begin{bmatrix} a_5=10 \\ a_4=12 \\ a_3=15 \\ a_2=20 \\ a_1=30 \end{bmatrix} \text{, which Albus had found. This preserves equality case because of condition of CS inequality.}$

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks to the hint of Albus Dumbledore:

\begin{align}
&\displaystyle {(10x_5+12x_4+15x_3+20x_2+30x_1)}_{(A)} \bigg(\dfrac 1 {10} + \dfrac 1 {12} + \dfrac 1 {15} + \dfrac 1 {20} + \dfrac 1 {30} \bigg)_{(B)} \geq \Big(\sum \sqrt{x_i}\Big)^2. \\
&A \leq 1200, B = \dfrac 1 3 \\
&\therefore \Big(\sum \sqrt{x_i} \Big)^2 \leq 400, \sum \sqrt{x_i} \leq 20. \\
\ \\
&\text{It is a solution when }x_1=4, x_2=9, x_3=16, x_4=25, x_5=36.
\end{align}